# How can I print a "header" line once when using write in Python when other lines are repeated multiple times?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have code which iterates through a file and copies selective data to file.txt.
However, for the first line, I want a header which will display "Header" just once.

```
with open ("file.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("Header \n")
    f.write(f"Something repeated for each found occurrence \n")
```

I tried:

```
with open ("file.txt", "a") as f:
   if "Header" in "file.txt":
       pass
   else:
       print ("Header")
   f.write("Header \n")
   f.write(f"Something repeated for each found occurrence \n")
```

But this repeats "Header" for every iteration. I would have assumed that if "Header" existed, then the code would move to the second `f.write` line.

Comment: Your `if "Header" in "file.txt"` - does not (and could not) do what you apparently expect.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I asked. I thought I should at least show what I had tried. Do you have any ideas?